# The footnote does not appear at all

Tags: footnotes

I used the simple code to make the footnote. The footnote is not showing at the page bottom as expected. Can you help me please?

This is my code

```
Hello world. \footnote{Hi there!}
```

Comment: Please add more details. Generally you need to provide a minimal example of a complete, compilable document that shows the problem.

Comment: are you using plain tex (in which case you are missing `\bye`) or latex (in which case you are missing (`\documentclass{article}\begin{document}..\end{document}`)do you mean you do not see a superscript 1 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Footnotes do not work in inner boxes like `\mbox`, `\parbox` or float objects.

Workarounds:

- `\footnotemark` inside the inner box and `\footnotetext{...}` outside.
- Environment `minipage` for local footnotes.
- Package `threeparttable` for tables with notes.
- ...
- To get the number in `\footnotetext`, the following can be used which is suitable in case you have just a few footnotes which can be numbered manually:

  ```
  The footnote goes here\textsuperscript{1}
  ```

  and the footnote text can be specified outside of `\mbox`, `\parbox` on the same page:

  ```
  \footnotetext{\textsuperscript{1}This is the footnote}}
  ```

  This does not work well with float objects, because the page with the float object is not known in general.