# How to make \footnotetext{} and \footnotemark{} so the footnote goes at the end of the page

Tags: footnotes

I am using the below, to make footnotes inside tabular. But my footnotes do not go at the end of the page. Instead, they stick at the empty space of the page after the text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,2pt]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=2pt,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%==========================auto counter for textboxes
\newcounter{textfieldCount}
\newcommand{\ATextField}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{textfieldCount}%
    \fbox{\TextField[name={textfield\thetextfieldCount},width=#2,#1]{}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{4cm}  c p{4cm} c }

PCB 1 input Voltage (No load)\footnotemark{} & \ATextField[width=4cm]{0cm} & PCB 2 input voltage (No load) & \ATextField[width=4cm]{0cm} \\

\end{tabular}

\footnotetext{Measure voltage on the input of the PCB, not the output of the power supply.}

\break


\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes not at the end of the text]

How can I make my footnotes go at the end of the page?

Note: [using `\footnote` does not work inside the tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262455/232956) so I cannot use `\footnote`.

Comment: do not use \break.

Comment: Okay, that helped. What if I wanted to use break though? In my initial code (before I strip everything else), I needed to use break.

Comment: are you sure you want \break and not \newpage? You can use `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay \newpage works for me. You can make your comments into answer so I can accept it :)